# Merge Two ColorMatrix or Apply two or more ColorMatrix simultaneously on Imageview

Tags: android, image-processing, android-imageview, android-image, colormatrix

I am changing Brightness, Contrast, Saturation and Hue of an ImageView. I have searched lot on it.

I got some code which works with **ColorMatrix.**

**[1.]** For **Brightness** ColorMatrix is some thing like

```
    float brightness = (-50F * 1.5F);
    ColorMatrix cmB = new ColorMatrix();
    cmB.set(new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
    0, 1, 0, 0,brightness,
    0, 0, 1, 0, brightness,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
    myImageView.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cmB));
```

which works Properly.

**[2.]** For **Contrast** ColorMatrix is something **Different**, which also works properly.

BUT, all these ColorMatrix works **individually**. Means the effect of last applied ColorMatrix is only scene on ImageView, because it does exactly it, which **removes effect of earlier applied** ColorMatrix and setups last applies ColorMatrix.

**Now I want to MERGE or mix-up ColorMatrix of All Simultaneously.** Means want to apply ColorMatrix of Contrast on the effect of ColorMatrix of Brightnrs / Saturation / Hue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply two color matrices, just multiply them together.

If you have color matrix A, and color matrix B, then :

```
C = B * A;
outpixel = C * inpixel
```

is equivalent to

```
outpixel = B * A * inpixel
```

EDIT

I just noticed that those are 5x4 matrices (originally I thought they were 4x4). Since you can't multiply them directly, I think would be appropriate to add a 5th identity row (0,0,0,0,1) to both matrices before multiplying (to make them both 5x5), and discard the 5th row after multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple matrices like that:

```
ColorMatrix colorFilterMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorFilterMatrix.postConcat(getContrastMatrix(contrast));
colorFilterMatrix.postConcat(getBrightnessMatrix(brightness));

imageView.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorFilterMatrix));
```